# JQuery Carousel images mis-aligned

Tags: jquery, css, image, alignment, carousel

I am trying to install a JQuery Carousel into a clients website, I have tried a couple of different ones and they both give the same issue, the images appear aligned far over to the right and up a little bit. I was wondering if anyone could take a quick look for me? The site is being built here: [www.samskirrow.com/client-hope](http://www.samskirrow.com/client-hope)

Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your menu and your tagline block are floated left.

A quick fix would be to add `clear: both` to your `mask` class.

I would recommend reading about [`clearfix`](http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/) solution for a better solution. This would entail adding the following CSS to your stylesheet and applying the class to floated elements.

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, I will read up on clearfix commands - I've never really understood them.